# Ruby on Rails 3.1 : unexpected to_json behaviour with arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following structure :

```
a = { 'x' => [1,2,3] }
```

In Rails 3.0 with ruby 1.8, the conversion to JSON works as expected :

> > a.to_json
>
> => "{\"x\":[1,2,3]}"

In Rails 3.1 with ruby 1.9.3p125, the array is transformed into a hash :

> > a.to_json
>
> => "{\"x\":{\"1\":null,\"2\":null,\"3\":null}}"

I can't find any documentation explaining the difference in behaviour between the two versions, nor any way to preserve the expected output in Rails 3.1. Any clues ?

Comment: I tested this on rails 3.1.3 and it does the first version, as in `"{\"x\":[1,2,3]}"`

Comment: I might have added that the Rails 3.1 server is running ruby 1.9.3 while the Rails 3.0 server runs ruby 1.8. I didn't think it had an effect.

Comment: my 3.1.3 is also running on ruby 1.9.3 :)

Comment: I don't have 3.1 handy, but with ruby 1.9.3-p125 and Rails 3.2.2, I get the correct conversion. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually related to one of the gems installed on the Gemfile, which returns an incorrect result for to_json calls.

Thanks for the help.